# Rust smart pointer issue

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, refcell

I'm trying to implement Church numerals

```rust
//! representation of natural numbers using lambda calculus, named after  
//! Alonzo Church. Each Church numeral corresponds to a natural number `n`  
//! and is represented as a higher-order function that applies a given function `f` `n` times.  
//! ex) f(f(f(x))) is equal to number 3
use std::rc::Rc;

/// Church numerals are represented as higher-order functions that take a function `f`
pub type Church<T> = Rc<dyn Fn(Rc<dyn Fn(T) -> T>) -> Rc<dyn Fn(T) -> T>>;


/// Implement a function to convert a Church numeral to a usize type.
pub fn to_usize<T: 'static + Default>(n: Church<T>) -> usize {
    use std::cell::RefCell;

    let counter = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));
    let counter_clone = Rc::clone(&counter);

    let result_func = n(Rc::new(move |x| {
        *counter_clone.borrow_mut() += 1;
        x
    }));

    let _ = result_func(Default::default());

    // Extract the value from the reference-counted cell
    let result = *counter.borrow();

    result
}
```

I'm trying to implement to_usize function, which convert given Church to it's corresponding value.
**However, counter value doesn't update and still remain zero.**
I think counter and counter_clone have same reference...

Comment: How do you invoke `to_usize()`? What do you pass into it?

Comment: Note that you can use [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) instead of `RefCell`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the behaviour of the code: with the correct input (a Church numeral), it produces the expected number.

```rust
println!("0: {}", to_usize(Rc::new(|f: Rc<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>| Rc::new(move |x| x))));
println!("1: {}", to_usize(Rc::new(|f: Rc<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>| Rc::new(move |x| f(x)))));
println!("2: {}", to_usize(Rc::new(|f: Rc<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>| Rc::new(move |x| f(f(x)))))));
println!("3: {}", to_usize(Rc::new(|f: Rc<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>| Rc::new(move |x| f(f(f(x)))))));
```

Outputs `0` through `3` as expected. Maybe the functions you were passing as input were not correct?

On a separate note, the type parameter of `to_usize` does not accurately capture what you would want from Church numeral, which is that it receives a function that is polymorphic in its input. Instead, the type parameter is constrained by `to_usize` and chosen at the call site, even though the call site does not make use of it. As a consequence, the way you are tracking "how many calls occurred" is using `RefCell` (which, as @Chayim pointed out in the comments, could be a `Cell`), which is suprising.

Ideally, `to_usize` could choose to instantiate the Church numeral with a `usize` type parameter, but this would require rank 2 polymorphism that Rust does not offer (`for <T> Rc<dyn Fn(T) -> T>`).

As a compromise, with an extra trait constraint:

```rust
pub fn to_usize<
    T: 'static + Default + std::ops::Add<usize, Output = T>
>(n: Church<T>) -> T {
    n(Rc::new(|x| x + 1))(Default::default())
}
```